# Unable to find xml file when running java program in cmd

Tags: xml, file, load

I used javapos in my project for the communication with a rfid printer. I developed it in Eclipse.
When I run the project in eclipse everything works fine.

But when I run it from `cmd` I get the error:

```
I/O warning : failed to load external entity "wineet.xml"
```

For testing I deleted `wineet.xml` and than I run the program in eclipse and I get the same error.

I know the `wineet.xml` must be in the root of the project.

And when I look in the `.jar` that I have created with Eclipse the `wineet.xml` is in the root of the project.

my run commands in `cmd` are:

```
java -Djna.library.path=C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560\drivers -classpath "C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\streamserve_print.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jcl.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jcl2.3.0-RC3.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jna-3.2.7.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jpos.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jpos113_controls.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jsr80-1.0.1.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jstrs.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\jstrscs.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\mtlgjpos-1.0.0.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\slf4j.api-1.6.1.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\slf4j.log4j12_1.5.2.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\xerces.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\xercesImpl.jar;C:\workspace_europe_32\StreamServePrintIER560_streamserve_print\lib\xml-apis-1.4.01.jar" print.PrintBitmap1
```

Can anyone help me with this problem?

thx

Answer (score 0):

The wineet.xml is in the root of the project but I think you are not running this command in the same directory (in the command prompt) this wineet.xml is present. So, it can't be found.

Comment: Thx a lot! Now it's working when I run the command in the same directory of the wineet.xml

Comment: Good! Please select as answer and close the question if your problem is resolved.